# Parent and child classes not referencing correctly within a function PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am building an MVC component and I'm getting stuck with an issue with a parent and child model.  I have a few methods in the parent Model and they're not working with the database_class object
the constructor works fine 
but when I use that object in the methods its like the constructor doesn't exist?

```
  Class Controlller 
      {


        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->childModel = $this->model('childModel');

        } // end construct


    // methods go here

    }
```

Here are the models:

```
 class childModel extends parentModel {


       private $dbo;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $dbobj = new Database_class;
            $this->dbo = $dbobj;

        }

    //methods


    }

class parentModel {

    private $dbom;

      public function __construct()
      {
        $dbombj = new Database_class;
        $this->dbom = $dbombj; 
       var_dump($this->dbom); //working perfectly as database object

      }

    public function methodName()
      {
        var_dump($this->dbom); //not showing up as database object
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this code is doing what you think it's doing.  In `childModel`, you are overwriting the `__construct` method of the parentModel, so the `__construct` in the parentModel never gets called.  Therefore `$this->dbom` should be null.  Furthermore if you wish to use `$this->dbom` from the childModel, you should probably change the scope from `private $dbom` to `protected $dbom`.  See this page for more info on that: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: I don't need to access $this->dbom from the child model.  But, I don't want to overwrite the _construct method of the parentModel so how do I fix that? I want to have both constructs working together?

Comment: You can use `parent::__construct();` within the `__construct()` of childModel to call it.

Comment: Doesn't this really defeat the purpose of 'extends' and parentModel - I don't want to have to do this for every childModel I have? If I remove the constructor for the childModel will the Parent constructor still be overridden?